# Use MemoryMappedFile as BinaryReader

Tags: memory, compact-framework

I'm using MemoryMappedFile(MMF) to put large files in memory. Working with memory limit 32MB. 50MB file is loaded using MMF for 2-3 seconds. Reading data from MMF works fine and fast.
The only problem for me is: I have big project with lot of using of BigEndianReader ( derived from BinaryReader) in multiple places. Instead of rewriting code - I prefer to modify this class to replace BinaryReader calls with MMF calls. Does anybody have idea how to create strteam from MMF? I have IntPtr for MMF but I dont understand how to create Stream from it.

Comment: It's worth noting that the SDF's MemoryMappedFile class already has all of this done and exposes it as a Stream.  http://opennetcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OpenNETCF/OpenNETCF/IO/MemoryMappedFile.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to subclass `Stream`, keep track of the stream's `Position` and the currently mapped segment:

```
public class MmfStream : Stream
{
    private IntPtr currentMap;
    private long mapOffset;
    private long mapSize;
    private long position;
```

The `Stream` base class requires you to implement a `Read` and `Write` method, so whenever the application tries to read or write, you can use `Marshal.Copy` to copy data from the currently mapped segment.

If the stream's `Position` gets beyond the mapped segment, you create a new map and provide information from the newly mapped segment. You'll also have to deal with having to access data from the current *and* the newly mapped view. Something like:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
{
    // current position not in current mapping?
    if (position < mapOffset)
    {
        // relocate the view
    }

    // compute how many bytes can be read from the current segment
    int read = Math.Min(size, (mapOffset + mapSize) - position);

    // copy those bytes to the buffer
    Marshal.Copy(...);

    position += read;

    if (size > read)
    {
        // recurse for the remaining bytes
        read += Read(buffer, offset + read, size - read);
    }

    return read;
}
```

(there are probably one-off errors in this code snippet; its just an illustration of the idea)